# How to rename a VirtualBox virtual machine (VM)?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I change the virtual machine's display name (displayed at the left-side pane of VirtualBox QT gui)?

I can't see any "rename" text in right-click menu.

I am using VirtualBox 4.3.14 on Linux.

Answer (score 59):

### From GUI

Shut down the machine, right-click on the machine, choose "Settings..." and from "General" tab -> "Basic" tab -> type in the "Name" box and click "OK".

### From terminal

Shut down that machine and type this in terminal:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm ORIGNAL_NAME --name NEW_NAME
```

If you get "command not found" error with `vboxmanage`, try the same wtih `VBoxManage` (uppercase command).

Comment: I think this only works if the VM is powered down.

Comment: Although the original question referred to Linux, maybe it could be useful for those who use VirtualBox on the Mac that the location of the VBoxManage command is /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage . Use this if you want to follow user2529583's advice on how to rename a VM on the command line. [NOTE: this was an answer but fixer1234 and JakeGould complained that it is rather a comment. So I put it here. Please yourselves.]

Comment: It seems silly that you can't change this for a "Saved" machine.

Comment: Thanks I found i couldn't modify a "saved" machine, had to first start it, then power down, then could change the name.

Comment: @clayton33, I found this as well.

Answer (score 11):

While [Babken Vardanyan](https://superuser.com/users/293360/babken-vardanyan)'s answer does indeed rename the VM and its directory, it does not rename the associated `.vdi` file (at least not on Windows.) If you wish to keep your machines renamed along with the `.vdi` files, an additional step is required, which involves renaming the **Location** field of the `.vdi` via Virtual Media Manager.

So, for the sake of fully renaming a VM *including* the `.vdi` as well:

1. Make sure the VM is off
2. RENAME VM:

   1. Right click VM > **Settings** > Left pane **General** > Right pane **Basic**
   2. Change **Name** field to reflect *new desired name* > **OK**
3. RENAME .vdi:

   1. **File** > **Virtual Media Manager**
   2. **Hard disks** tab > scroll to relevant `.vdi` > Right-click `.vdi` > **Properties** > **Attributes** tab opens below (if not already opened)
   3. In the **Location** field, change *only* the `.vdi` *part of the path* e.g. D:\VB\MACHINE\***MACHINE.vdi*** to reflect *new desired name*
   4. Click **Apply**

(This was done on Windows VirtualBox v6.1.2).

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. Thanks.